# Implementation of printf for new data type (vector)

Tags: c, vector, printf

I have implemented `printf` for vector type. The values in vector type are represented as (element1,element2,...) For example for vector of size 3, a possible value could be (1,2,3)

My implementation for `printf` is:

```
int my_printf(const char *format,...)
{
    va_list args;
    int argSize = 1; // get the number of elemts in vector
    const char* vec;
    vec = strchr(format,'v');
    if(vec != NULL)
        argSize = atol(vec + 1);
    va_start (args, format);
    int i = 0,ret = 0;

    do // print all elements
    {
        ret = vprintf ("%d ", args);
        fflush(stdout);
        va_arg(args,float);
    } while(i < argSize);
    va_end (args); 

    return ret; 
}

int main()
{
    my_printf("v3",(10,12,13));
    return 0;
}
```

While `va_start (args, format);` args gets value 13 prints it and for the next two printings prints 0 (args = 0)
What could be the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(10,12,13)` represent the single number 13. It's [comma operator](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4db.html), quite peculiar feature of C language.

So your code is equivalent to this:

```
int temp = (10,12,13); // now temp == 13
my_printf("v3", temp);
```

In C, there is no vector type as it's known from C++. There are only arrays. You could initialize array like this:

```
int array[] = {10, 12, 13};
```

--and use the array as an argument for `my_printf`.

Comment: I can`t declare tmp to be int it is not correct - it is of the new vector  type

Comment: @Shahbaz - This solution is incorrect - I tried it in mvs - it generates 13 0 0

Comment: In C99 you could also do `my_printf("v3", (int []){ 10, 12, 13 });` to pass a stack-allocated array "literal."

Comment: @Yakov: I am trying to explain what did you _actually_ do. You, in your code, _indeed_ passed an `int`, not an array. I am not _proposing_ it, I'm pointing to your mistake.

Comment: @ Vlad,@ Chris Lutz - the request for vector type data representation in my system is (element1,element2,...)

Comment: @Yakov: but not in C language! In C the arrays are not represented like that. And the developers have no control over it.

Comment: @ Chris Lutz,@Vlad - The solution you present gives wrong output: I changed the code to int tmp[] = {10,12,13};
my_printf("v3",tmp);   //The result is 3210576 0 0

Comment: @Yakov: okay, now this is a problem with `my_printf` itself.

Comment: @ Vlad - what is the problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4431/discussion-between-yakov-and-vlad)

Comment: @Yakov: there are several. One of them: `ret = vprintf ("%d ", args);` is wrong. Array is nothing but a pointer to its 1st item, you are printing it as if it were an integer.

Comment: @Vlad - how you propose to print it?//*args && args[0] can`t be compiled

Comment: You need to cast the type to whatever is correct. Or you can do the pointer arithmetics manually.